# OAuth provider that authenticates only by phone?

Tags: oauth, oauth2

I'm trying to find an OAuth provider that doesn't require a password but instead, it authenticates the user by sending a message to a phone number. I'm thinking that it would be using the phone the same way as you would use two-factor-authentication but without the password.

So far I couldn't find any. Does such provider exist?

If it does exist then what risks associated with such a use-case do you see?

Thanks!

Comment: Google `sim swapping`. If you're have any security concerns, this will prove weak. If you're only using authentication to handle something like theme customization, then maybe it's OK.

Comment: This doesn't do it by phone number but does eliminate the password part of authentication: https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "what product/service does X?" are off-topic as the answer might change from day to day

Comment: SMS as an authentication factor has been deemed insecure for a while now.

Comment: I wasn't aware of sim swapping. Thanks for the pointers. Also sqrl looks interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not, it's not based on [FIDO](https://fidoalliance.org/)

Look up *sim swapping*.